# What are Hermitian conjugates in this context?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, terminology

I am having trouble understanding the definition Hermitian and Hermitian conjugate.

An operator is Hermitian provided that:  $\hat{O}^\dagger=\hat{O}$

The Hermitian conjugate of the differentiation operator: $\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^\dagger=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$

We know that the differentiation operator is not a Hermitian then why is it called a Hermitian conjugate and not just a conjugate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hermitian is an adjective used to describe an operator which is equal to its Hermitian conjugate.

Hermitian conjugate (sometimes also called Hermitian adjoint) is a noun referring to the generalisation of the conjugate transpose of a matrix.

It doesn't really make sense to say that a particular operator is a Hermitian conjugate without any context. In your example, we would say that $-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is the Hermitian conjugate of $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$.

Comment: ok thank you i understand. Just because a we found a Hermitian conjugate of an operator it doesn't have to mean that operator is Hermitian unless they are equal

Comment: @JackJack Yes. But finding a Hermitean conjugate is a delicate business in general. The modern mathematical terminology speaks of adjoint, instead of Hermitean conjugate. This latter wording is kept in matrix (i.e. finite-dimensional case) algebra.

Answer (score 5):

The Hermitian Conjugate or Hermitian Transpose of an operator $\hat{O}$ is defined as  $\hat{O}^\dagger$.

As you stated in your question an operator $\hat{Q}$ is Hermitian iff $\hat{Q}=\hat{Q}^\dagger$, I know the terminology can be confusing. An operator is Hermitian if it is equal to its Hermitian Conjugate.

Now to the differentiation operator: I assume you know why $\frac{d}{dx}^\dagger=-\frac{d}{dx}$ since its in your question but here is a link that describes it if you are unsure: [Explaining why $\mathrm{ d/d}x$ is not Hermitian, but $\mathrm{i~ d/d}x$ is Hermitian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292435/explaining-why-mathrm-d-dx-is-not-hermitian-but-mathrmi-d-dx-is-herm)

Clearly $\frac{d}{dx}^\dagger \neq \frac{d}{dx}$, so the operator is $\textbf{not}$ Hermitian, but we can still just find its Hermitian Conjugate same as any other operator.

Comment: Would you be able to help with the second part?

Comment: By * do you mean complex conjugate or Hermitian Conjugate? Textbooks sometimes swap notation and its really annoying, im not sure which one you are referring to since I dont think you are interested in only complex conjugating based on your previous question; and you also used the other convention earlier